# ¿Cómo reinstalar los drivers de video en Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, video, screen

Muy buena tardes. Tengo un problema en el funcionamiento de Ubuntu, pocos minutos despues de prendido el computador, hay partes de la pantalla que se bloquean y quedan permanentes en la pantalla a pesar de que se cambia de pantalla.

Adjunto un ejemplo de mi pantalla escrbiendo este mensaje, el bug o problema se reporta en el medio del lado derecho[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Tengo un Lenovo G480: Intel HD Graphics 4000

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Que vídeo tienes?

Comment: Tengo un Lenovo G480: Intel HD Graphics 4000

Comment: Busque la solucion para 16.04 que utiliza una versión 2.0.2 de intel, pero al parecer intel ya no lo tiene disponible en su pagina oficial de drivers. La mayoría de personas vi que solucionaron reinstalando el sistema.

Answer (score 0):

He visto que el [PPA de padoka](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa) funciona para algunas personas, en Ubuntu 16.04.

Después de agregar el PPA a apt, hice lo siguiente:

1. `sudo apt upgrade libglapi-mesa libgl1-mesa-dri vulkan-utils`
2. Por algún motivo, veo que las personas tienen que crear un enlace simbólico adicional para el controlador intel:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libvulkan_intel.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so`

Espero te pueda servir de algo!

**Como información adicional** [Respuesta Original](https://askubuntu.com/a/28036) de esta información:

En Linux, hay dos partes para el controlador de video, la parte del kernel y la parte del servidor X.

1. Primero identifiquemos su hardware. Al escribir `spci | grep VGA` en una terminal, debería ver una línea con su descripción de la tarjeta gráfica (incluso si no está configurada).
2. Comprobemos que el controlador del kernel correcto esté cargado `find /dev -group video`.
3. Vamos a verificar que el controlador X correcto esté cargado `glxinfo | grep -i vendor`.

Si desea más ayuda, me gustaría obtener los siguientes comandos: ( **Recuerde, nunca confíe en la línea de comando que la gente le pide que ejecute sin saber lo que hace** ) .

```
lspci | grep VGA ; lsmod | grep "kms\|drm" ; find /dev -group video ; \
cat /proc/cmdline ; find /etc/modprobe.d/; cat /etc/modprobe.d/*kms* ; \
ls /etc/X11/xorg.conf ; glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering" ; \
grep LoadModule /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

> Además aquí [Instalación de controladores de la manera oficial](https://askubuntu.com/a/50514) (Traducir del Inglés).